# Why is ENC28J60 getting as hot as 65°C?

Tags: atmega, ethernet, atmega328p, enc28j60

I am working on an Ethernet adapter and I am using ENC28J60 as SPI slave an ATMEGA328P as SPI master. The adapter works fine, but ENC28J60 really gets hot, measured with infrared thermometer and it reaches 65°C. From what I have read, the ENC28J60 runs hot, but usually between 45-50°C.

I have prototype boards made and assembled 3 of them, same problem on all boards, so I guess I made some fault in the schematics:

[image]

Any advice highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! Wild guess: are the LED outputs internally current limited or 3.3 V output and you have "shorted" them with straight LED to ground?

Comment: It looks like your schematic is incomplete. Some of your signals are not connected to anything. Can you please edit your post to add the complete schematic? Also it looks like some signals (e.g. ETH_CS_5V) aren't being level shifted. Not familiar with this chip specifically, but is that intended?

Comment: Have you perhaps read this : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/154076/hot-enc28j60-chip?rq=1 (?)

Comment: Where do the LED pins go? Why RBIAS is incorrect?

Comment: @MattS : The ENC28J60 should be 5V tolerant, so I only level shifted the ENC28J60 outputs which lead to the ATMEGA328P, from 3V3 to 5V. I have updated the image to show the entire schematics.

Comment: @winny : Thanks for your welcome! I have updated the schematics in the OP with the full schematics. I connected the LED with the ENC28J60 with a current limiting resistor to ground. The ENC28J60 also gets hot without LEDs installed.

Comment: @Justme : I have updated the schematics to show the full circuit. Not sure why I used a 1K resistor for the RBIAS, the datasheet says 2.32K 1%. Do you think this might cause the issue?

Comment: @Justme : Now replaced RBIAS resistor with a 2.32K resistor and the ENC28J60 runs at 45°C and the adapter still works fine! If you write a short answer, I will accept it as the solution if you want. Thanks!

Comment: Good, then that's ruled out. For future reference, please draw all your positive voltages pointing upwards, ground and negative pointing down (C1). Inputs from left and outputs to right (your voltage regulator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using incorrect Rbias resistor which sets the internal current sources to incorrect values.

The chip requires a 2.32 Kohm 1% resistor to work properly and use the correct current and voltage levels on Ethernet interface.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!